# How to keep 4 Linux kernels in /boot by default before they are removed automatically

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel

I did some digging around and found that the automatic clean-up for kernels is in `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal` and the file states:

```
# In the common case this results in two kernels saved (booted into the
# second-latest kernel, we install the latest kernel in an upgrade), but
# can save up to four. Kernel refers here to a distinct release, which can
# potentially be installed in multiple flavours counting as one kernel.
```

but that script is way above my head and I cannot easily find how autoclean anything but the last 4 kernels.

Comment: You have to modify the script in several places, there is no other way. If you wish, you can file a "wishlist" bug report on the `apt` package to allow the number of kernels to be customised.

Comment: The "four" in the part you quoted refers to the unusual case where "the currently booted version", "the kernel version we've been called for", "the latest kernel version", and "the second-latest kernel version" are all distinct, since all those versions are kept. In typical cases, however, this boils down to two because "the currently booted version" and "the second-latest kernel version" are the same, and likewise for the two others.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What it means when it says "up to four" is that the currently running, current installed, latest, and previous versions can all be different, resulting in four versions being automatically kept (with a minimum of two). See this part of the code:

```sh
debkernels="$(echo "$latest_version
$installed_version
$running_version
$previous_version" | sort -u | sed -e '/^$/ d')"
```

I think the simplest way to get it to save older kernels would be to extend the `$previous_version` to a list. Instead of:

```sh
previous_version="$(echo "$debverlist" | sed -n 2p)"
```

Do:

```sh
previous_version="$(echo "$debverlist" | sed -n 2,4p)"
```

Comment: Yes, this looks like it should work. One should note that since the file is part of the `apt` package, it could be reverted to the default one when `apt` is upgraded.

Comment: @fkraiem the file is in `/etc`, so it's presumably a conffile and changes should be preserved (or, at least, the user will be asked about them)

Comment: Yes, all files under `/etc` are conffiles, but it seems users often get confused when the "keep or replace?" question pops up...

Comment: I won't get confused...  @fkraiem

Comment: apt still complains: `The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.10.0-38 linux-headers-4.10.0-38-generic
  linux-image-4.10.0-38-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-38-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.10.0-38-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
` but that's an executable and I'll stop worrying about it and have adapted the question to fit the answer.   **:-)**

Comment: Nice answer but above my paygrade. Here's a new question you might be able to answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1325387/why-is-apt-get-autoremove-failing-to-remove-my-old-kernels